# use setState to change my arrays of object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {
      Component
    } from "react";
    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        RSVP: [{
          name: ["IronMan"],
          isConfirmed: false
        }]
      };
      handleChecked = () => {
        this.setState({
          isConfirmed: true
        }););
    };
    render() {
        return ( < div > {
              this.state.RSVP && this.state.RSVP.length != 0 ? this.state.RSVP.map(({
                name,
                isConfirmed
              }) => name && name.length != 0 ? ( <
                div key = {
                  name
                } > {
                  name
                } < input type = "checkbox"
                checked = {
                  isConfirmed
                }
                onChange = {
                  this.handleChecked
                }
                /></div > ) : null) : null
            } < /div>);}}
            export default App;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. Please try and fix the syntax errors in your code, indent it, and elaborate on what you are struggling with.

Comment: thanks @Frankez for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change state of object inside an array you can use the following source code:

```
handleChange = (index) => {
  let tmp = [...this.state.RSVP];
  tmp[index] = {...tmp[index],isConfirmed: true};
  this.setState({RSVP: tmp})
}
```